# how to apply gvim regular expressions to multiple files

Tags: regex, vim

How to apply regular expressions to multiple files in gvim ?

Comment: What does "apply regular expressions" even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try opening all files in tab mode i.e gvim -p file1 file2 .....

then do :tabdo

Comment: Or buffers, with `$ vim file1 file2 …` and `:bufdo …`. Or windows, with `$ vim -o file1 file2 …` and `:windo …`.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to assume "apply regular expressions", means use a substitution via `:s` over many files.

Vim does not come with an "all-in-one" native project-wide find & replace command. Instead it is typically a two step process:

- Collect locations/files/buffers/windows/tabs
- Apply a command over the collection with a *do command

#### Arg list

The arg list is simply a list of files. You can populate it when you start Vim, e.g. `vim *.txt` or via `:args` once Vim has started.

```
:args *.txt
:argdo %s/foo/bar/g | w
```

#### Quickfix/Location List

The quickfix (& location list) are simply a list of locations, e.g. file, line, column. You can populate these lists with many commands, e.g. `:vimgrep`, `:grep`, `:make`, `:cexpr`, etc. Use `:cdo` to run a command over each location. `:cfdo` will run a command over each file in the list.

```
:vimgrep /foo/ **/*.txt
:cfdo %s/foo/bar/g | w
```

Many people like to use `:grep` as you can customize the `'grepprg'` to use a fast grep alternative, e.g [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/). I would also [recommend mapping](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) `:cnext` & `:cprev`.

#### Buffers

You can run a command on all opened buffers with `:bufdo`. Use `:ls` to see what buffers you have open.

```
:bufdo %s/foo/bar/g | w
```

## Windows

Can run a command over all windows in a the current tab page with `:windo`. This is helpful to do diff'ing via `:windo diffthis`.

```
:windo %s/foo/bar/g | w
```

#### Tabs

Run a command over all tabs via `:tabdo`.

```
:tabdo %s/foo/bar/g | w
```

#### Assorted tips

Some thoughts for better find & replace workflows.

- Use the `e` flag to prevent `:s` from stopping when no match can be found.
- May want to build your search pattern ahead of time then use `:s//{replacment}` to avoid typing out the pattern again.
- Look into using [traces.vim](https://github.com/xtal8/traces.vim) to give a visual feedback for substitutions.
- As with all project-wide substitutions it is best to use some sort of version control (e.g. git, mercurial, svn) in case something goes terribly wrong.

Personally, I typically use quickfix list for most of my multiple file substitutions. I use `:grep` with ripgrep for fast project searching.

#### For more help see:

Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes:

- [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/)
- [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)
- [Using :argdo to change multiple files](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/)

Also see:

```
:h :s
:h :bar
:h arglist
:h :argdo
:h quickfix
:h :cdo
:h :grep
:h :vimgrep
:h 'grepprg'
:h buffer
:h :bufdo
:h window
:h :windo
:h tabpage
:h :tabdo
```